Missing solana payment that was made via stripe
I purchased solana on the phantom app about 24 hrs ago through the Stripe payment via apple pay. The money has been taken out of my account but I have still yet to receive any funds. I have a screenshot of the payment completed via Stripe. Phantom automatically pasted the Solana address into stripe during my payment.
